# What does it mean "Laplace transformable functions"

Tags: calculus, analysis, laplace-transform

I am reading about the [The convolution operation](http://www.math.vt.edu/people/dlr/m2k_opm_convol.pdf), and the notion Laplace transformable functions is mentioned there.

Doe anyone know what is the definition of Laplace transformable functions?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is doubtless meant by $f(x)$ being *Laplace transformable* is that $\int_0^\infty e^{-sx} f(x) \, dx$ converges, at least for certain values of $s \in \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

See also [Chapter 5](https://books.google.nl/books?id=LfTNdPDLOkYC&pg=SA5-PA1&lpg=SA5-PA1&dq=Laplace+transformable+functions&source=bl&ots=CHq53fkVUs&sig=6zshtDo1RU7hB2IhUd9ELIjBVVc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MLlpVYCjM6auygO0moHYCg&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=Laplace%20transformable%20functions&f=false) of *Transforms and Applications Handbook*, 3rd ed., Poularikas.

Comment: ok will give it a try. Thanks!